# I can't upgrade libgtk-3-0

Tags: pi-4, update

```
$ apt list --upgradable -a
```

Listing... Done
libgtk-3-0/stable 3.24.24-4+rpt5+deb11u2 armhf [upgradable from: 3.24.24-4+rpt4+deb11u2]
libgtk-3-0/now 3.24.24-4+rpt4+deb11u2 armhf [installed,upgradable to: 3.24.24-4+rpt5+deb11u2]
libgtk-3-0/stable 3.24.24-4+deb11u2 armhf

so I put

```
sudo apt upgrade libgtk-3-0
```

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgtk-3-0 : Depends: libwayland-client0 (>= 1.20.0) but 1.18.0-2~exp1.1 is to be installed
Recommends: libgtk-3-bin but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages

Please help me upgrade it

Comment: Post your `sources.list`.

Comment: Does https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=340648#p2041092 address your problem?

Comment: Yes thank you, will try again later